# ReactJS running different code on client and server.

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using https://github.com/andreypopp/react-quickstart to render pages serverside, before letting them update dynamically on the client.

Some pages require data from the server.  When running on the client, they get this via `superagent`.

During the initial (server-side) render, I would like `getInitialState` for the page to get it's data directly.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways you could go about this.

The template you're using, react-quickstart,  uses audreypopp's react-async add-on to handle rendering components with async state.  There's a section in its README that goes over this exact scenario: https://github.com/andreypopp/react-async#rendering-async-components-on-server-with-fetched-async-state.

Basically, you can add a third argument to the callback function of `ReactAsync.renderComponentToStringWithAsyncState`, which points to a snapshot of your current server state.  The README provides the following example:

```
ReactAsync.renderComponentToStringWithAsyncState(
  Component(),
  function(err, markup, data) {
    res.send(ReactAsync.injectIntoMarkup(markup, data, ['./client.js']))
})
```

`injectIntoMarkup` injects the pre-fetched state data as a JSON blob which can be referenced elsewhere in your code as `window.__reactAsyncStatePacket`.

The other way to do this does not use react-async. Instead, you can call `React.renderComponentToString`, passing your pre-fetched server data as `props`.

```
var markup = React.renderComponentToString(
    Item({ data: SERVER_DATA })
);
```

**Note**: You'll have to add some conditional logic to your component code to differentiate between receiving your state directly as `props` or via ajax/superagent, but it should be straightforward.

Now, for For the sake of this example, let say you're using Handlebars/Express, you can inject your component string into a template:

```
res.render('template', {
    markup: markup
});
```

And your template:

```
<div id="container">{{{ markup }}}</div>
```

Finally, to get your component working nicely on the client, you can call `React.renderComponent` as you normally would on the client. React knows not to replace components that were just rendered from the server, but *will* re-render them when necessary in the future.

Hope this helps, and happy to answer any questions!

Comment: @chrisdew was that helpful?  Let me know if you have any lingering questions.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'll accept it once I get some time to try it.

Answer (score 0):

`react-quickstart` was doing what I needed already.

I had an issue in that I didn't realise that `getInitialStateAsync` is only called on classes which use the mixin `ReactAsync.Mixin`.

E.g.

```
var UserPage = React.createClass({
  mixins: [ReactAsync.Mixin],

  statics: {
    getUserInfo: function(username, cb) {
      superagent.get(
        'http://localhost:3000/api/users/' + username,
        function(err, res) {
          cb(err, res ? res.body : null);
        });
    }
  },

  getInitialStateAsync: function(cb) {
    this.type.getUserInfo(this.props.username, function(arg0, arg1) {
      cb(arg0, arg1)
    });
  },

  ...
```